submit, ngSubmit or click+keydown.enter for Angular 18+ and good accessibility?
Is there a consensus on the proper way to submit a form and have a good accessibility?
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

or
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

or
<form>
  <button type="submit"
    (click)="onSubmit()"
    (keydown.enter)="onSubmit()"
    >Submit</button>
</form>

Using click and keyboard seems to be bad practice for accessibility.
Is implicit submission (submit on enter key) useful to people using readers and keyboard navigation?
ngSubmit seemed preferred in old answers for Angular 2, but is it still true?
submit vs ngSubmit in Angular 2
Difference between angular submit and ngSubmit events?

method 2 is best since it work on press of enter key, without any extra code, and ngSubmit because its provided by angular, out of the box

You will not find a 100% consensus and I would start with none. I would state then that an "input type submit" would be a more accessible way. As such this will come down to own experience, opinions, and standards. Unless there is a WCAG instruction it will be opinion-based

This isn't opinion-based. Handling click on the submit button doesn't cover the case of pressing enter while the focus  is in another control, so it's objectively much worse for accessibility. Then between native or Angular submit, assuming that the framework is well developed, you should probably prefer  using tools it provides to you, as it may handle corner cases the native version don't handle by default.
